# Assembly rdtsc x64 ubuntu

Tags: c, assembly, rdtsc

I'm trying to use rdtsc function but i've got weird numbers. I'm trying to call this function from C code and pass the tick back to function. Can you tell me if im doing it right or not ?

Asm code:

```
.text

.globl czas
.type czas, @function

czas:
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp
xor %rax,%rax;
cpuid
rdtsc
popq %rbp
ret
```

C code:

```
unsigned long long Czas;
Czas=czas();
```

Comment: yes, but i've got something like this:
Czas dla FPU: 18446744069679515163

Comment: Have you tried [using this instead](http://www.cs.wm.edu/~kearns/001lab.d/rdtsc.html) ?

Comment: no, i need it in another assembly file.

Answer (score 3):

`rdtsc` returns result in `edx`:`eax` even in 64 bit mode, but C calling convention expects result in `rax`. You have to pack the result yourself. Note you don't typically need a stack frame for this.
Something like:

```
cpuid
rdtsc
shl $32, %rdx
or %rdx, %rax
ret
```

Comment: For a bit of historical context, http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21249 (not a bug because `rdtsc` in 64bit mode works differently ... but people stumble over this for the last ten years)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of type is your function?
It should be UINT64.
`rdtsc` return low 32 bits in EAX and high 32 bits in EDX register.
So is you wont result in RAX than perform:

```
  shl   rdx, 32     //left shift for 32 bits
  or    rax, rdx    //Compose both registers in 64 bit RAX
```

after executing `rdtsc` instruction.